# require an external module in jade in a node.js webserver

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I need to require a util module in my jade template to do some checking.

Can I do that? I tried following in a jade template which sits in `$ROOT/views/jade/sample.jade`

```
var utils = require('../../app/server/modules/queries.js')
```

for a module that sits in

```
$ROOT/app/server/modules/queries.js
```

But it does not work.

Can I do what I want????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can register helpers from within Express.

In a request handler.

```
var utils = require('../../app/server/modules/queries.js')
function(req, res) {
  res.render("sample", {
    locals: {
      title: "Welcome to Derpco",
      someUtilFunction: utils.someUtilFunction
    }
  });
};
```

Also you can register helpers globally using `app.locals.helpername = ...`

Comment: @user2384694 Don't forget to accept this answer since it's working!