# module "require" inside a Jade file

Tags: node.js, pug

I need to use "fs" module inside a Jade file. No other JS file.

When I try:

```
- var js = require('fs')
- var downloadfiles = readdirSync("download") 
for f in downloadfiles
  url
    loc= D + "/download" + f
    lastmod= buildDate
    changefreq daily
    priority 1.0
```

I got the error "undefined is not a function"

Comment: possible duplicate of [require an external module in jade in a node.js webserver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407998/require-an-external-module-in-jade-in-a-node-js-webserver)

Answer (score 7):

Two problems


You should send the function to the Jade file as an argument rather than trying to require it in Jade ie.

```
var js = require('fs');
res.render('myjadefile', {fsFunction: fs});
```

myjadefile.jade

```
- var downloadfile = fsFunction.readdirSync('download');
for f in downloadfiles
   // rest of your code
```

Also, in line 2 you are calling function "readdirSync" without defining it anywhere.  It should be

```
fs.readdirSync
```

Answer (score 3):

```
res.render(index, {data:data,
                   title:'Jade Require'
                   require:require})
```

Now in your jade.

```
extends layout
!{fs=require('fs')}


body
  - var downloadfiles = readdirSync("download") 
  for f in downloadfiles
    url
      loc= D + "/download" + f
      lastmod= buildDate
      changefreq daily
      priority 1.0
```